# Issue with Javascript in Posting system

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

So, I have a posting system. When you type a post in the input field and click the submit button, the post displays with the help of PHP and AJAX.

Now on that post are stuff like a like button and comment button, and when you click the like button, it turns blue. Now, after making a post and the post displaying, clicking the like button will make it blue. However, let's say you make another post. For that post, everything works, except when you click the like button on the second or third post, it makes the like button on the first post only turn blue, similarly with the comment button. Also, the first post has a background color of silver (#C0C0C0), however any other post, like the second or third post, don't. They have no background color.

This stuff (turning blue on click) is accomplished using JavaScript. What I identified from this is that the JS isn't working for any other post besides the first post. To resolve this, I tried changing the position of the JS in the code because I thought it had something to do with the scope, but it didn't. Please help, with the JS and the background color issue.

PHP/HTML/CSS Code:

```
<style>
.textPost {
  margin-top: 170px;
  width: 650px;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  margin-left: 685px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.textpostFormat {
  margin-left: -640px;
  position: fixed;
}
</style>

<div class="textPost">
  <?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  ?>
  <div class="textpostFormat" id="textpostFormat">
          <img src="img/pfp.png" alt="pfp" onclick="location.href='profile.php'" class="textpostPFP">
    <b><div class="textinfo"><?php echo $firstname . "&nbsp;" . $lastname ?></div></b>
    <img src="img/options.png" alt="textpostOptions" class="textpostOptions">
    <hr style="margin-top: 85px; width: 600px; position: fixed; margin-left: 663px; border:1px solid black; border-radius: 10px">
    <hr style="margin-top: 200px; width: 600px; position: fixed; margin-left: 663px; border:1px solid black; border-radius: 10px">
    <div class="textfeedbackBar" style="position: fixed">
      <hr style="margin-top: 250px; width: 600px; position: fixed; margin-left: 663px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px">
      <div class="textratingBar">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer">1</div>
        <hr style="width: 0px; height: 43px; float: left; margin-top: -2px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer">2</div>
        <hr style="width: 0px; height: 43px; float: left; margin-top: -2px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer">3</div>
        <hr style="width: 0px; height: 43px; float: left; margin-top: -2px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer">4</div>
        <hr style="width: 0px; height: 43px; float: left; margin-top: -2px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer">5</div>
        <hr style="width: 0px; height: 43px; float: left; margin-top: -2px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer">6</div>
        <hr style="width: 0px; height: 43px; float: left; margin-top: -2px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer">7</div>
        <hr style="width: 0px; height: 43px; float: left; margin-top: -2px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer">8</div>
        <hr style="width: 0px; height: 43px; float: left; margin-top: -2px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; margin: 10px; cursor: pointer">9</div>
        <hr style="width: 0px; height: 43px; float: left; margin-top: -2px; border: 1px solid black">
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 275px; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 10px; position: fixed">10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr style="margin-top: 320px; width: 600px; position: fixed; margin-left: 663px; border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px">
    <img src="img/pfp.png" alt="commentpfp" onclick="location.href='profile.php'" class="textcommentPFP">
    <input type="text" name="textComment" class="textComment" id="textComment" placeholder="Write a comment">
    <p style="margin-left: 670px; margin-top: 95px; position: fixed; font-size: 45px; font-family: 'Rajdhani'"><?php echo $row["body"]; ?></p>
    <div class="textPostData" style="position:fixed; font-family: 'Rajdhani'; margin-left: 820px; margin-top: 150px">
      <h4 id="textDataLikes" style="cursor: pointer">0 Likes</h4>
      <h4 id="textDataComments" style="margin-left: 102px; margin-top: -42px; cursor: pointer">0 Comments</h4>
      <h4 id="textDataReactions" style="margin-left: 240px; margin-top: -42px; cursor: pointer">0 Reactions</h4>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 715px; position: fixed; font-family: 'Rajdhani'">
      <h2 style="margin-top: 206px; margin-left: -30px; cursor:pointer; padding: 5px; position: fixed" class="textLike" id="textLike" onclick="textLikeClick()"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like</h2>
      <h2 style="margin-left: 99px; margin-top: 206px; cursor:pointer; padding: 5px; position: fixed" class="makeComment" id="makeComment" onclick="textCommentClick()"><i class="fa fa-comment" style="margin-top: 2px;"></i> Comment</h2>
      <h2 style="margin-left: 290px; margin-top: 206px; cursor:pointer; padding: 5px; position: fixed" class="textReact" id="textReact"><i class="fa fa-smile" style="margin-top: 2px;"></i> React</h2>
      <h2 style="margin-left: 432px; margin-top: 206px; cursor:pointer; padding: 5px; position: fixed" class="textShare" id="textShare"><i class="fa fa-share" style="margin-top: 2px"></i> Share</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 398px; margin-top: 236px">
    <img class="textupvote" id="textUpvoteImg" src="img/upvote.png" alt="upvote" onclick="changetextUpvote()" style="width: 100px; margin-bottom: 28px; cursor: pointer">
    <img class="textdownvote" id="textDownvoteImg" src="img/downvote.png" alt="downvote" onclick="changetextDownvote()" style="width: 55px; margin-top: 32px; margin-left: 21px; position: fixed; cursor: pointer">
  </div>
  <?php

  }
}

  ?>
  </div>
  <?php

  }
}

  ?>
</div>
```

AJAX code (to display posts without page refresh):

```
function makePost() {
  var postContent = $("#postContent").val();
  if (postContent.length > 0) {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url:"yourposts.php",
      data:{
        postContent: postContent
      },
      type:"POST",
      success:function(data){
        if (data == "success") {
          $("#textpostFormat").html(postContent);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Javascript code (for turning like button blue and stuff):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changetextUpvote() {
  var textUpvoteImg = document.getElementById('textUpvoteImg');
  if (textUpvoteImg.src.match("orangeupvote")) {
    textUpvoteImg.src = "img/upvote.png";
  } else {
    textUpvoteImg.src = "img/orangeupvote.png";
    textDownvoteImg.src = "img/downvote.png";
  }
}

function changetextDownvote() {
  var textDownvoteImg = document.getElementById('textDownvoteImg');
  if (textDownvoteImg.src.match("orangedownvote")) {
    textDownvoteImg.src = "img/downvote.png";
  } else {
    textDownvoteImg.src = "img/orangedownvote.png";
    textUpvoteImg.src = "img/upvote.png";
  }
}

function textLikeClick() {
  document.getElementById('textLike').style.color = "blue";
}

function textCommentClick() {
  document.getElementById('textComment').focus();
}

</script>
```

Comment: You're using the same ID value within a loop (`id="textpostFormat"`). IDs must be unique in a document

Comment: So what do I do? Where do I change the id? In the <div> in the HTML? Or in the AJAX?

Comment: Simply adding `// all the post content (like, comment buttons, etc.)` is not helpful ~ please add actual content that accurately reflects the markup

Comment: I'm trying to understand what @Phil said. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: perhaps - but please add the markup otherwise what I do post will not reflect your problem and likely confuse you further

Comment: That post content is way too long to post. Could you tell me what @Phil meant though. Please.

Comment: Every ID must be unique - otherwise it is not truly an identity. As you repeat the same IDs throughout (in the loop) Javascript does not know which element you actually mean when you call `document.getElementById` - should it be the first, last, middle ??? One way to do it is to use the `event` ( ie: the `click event` ) and find elements from that

Comment: You misunderstand the requirement for the markup! You mention buttons and images yet the snippet glosses over that with the meaningless `all the post content (like, comment buttons, etc.)` ~ simply add the buttons, images and other relevant items from a single div ( class='textpostFormat') ~ not the actual full content such as words.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius So what should I do right now? Should I change the id? Where should I change the id? Could you give me steps for it?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius In it, I have the post with a background color of silver (which isn't displaying for any other post besides the first one), and then the body of the post, through PHP, like and comment buttons, and a comment input, which when you click the comment button, the input gets focus, and when you click the like button, the like button turns blue, for which is working for just the first post, not any other post, like the second or third or fourth post.

Comment: I'll post some example code based upon what I have seen but without seeing the real markup it is impossible to be more precise. You will need to study this and see how you can implement this with whatever code you do have. The `click` handler function uses `this` to access the object (button) that invoked the `click event` - from that event (event.target ) it is possible to identify other DOM elements within the same parent or sibling nodes.

Comment: Hey I didn't really understand your answer. Really, I just wanted you to answer what @Phil meant when he said "you're using the same ID value within a loop (id="textpostFormat"). IDs must be unique in a document."

Comment: Is this a JS problem, an HTML problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: It's a JS problem.

Comment: If this is a JS problem, please remove all other irrelevant parts from the question (code and tags) such that it contains soleley those parts that are not working yet

Answer (score 0):

None of the elements here have an ID attribute. Identification of elements is done based upon inspecting the event.target and navigating around the DOM using `querySelector`, `parentNode` and perhaps other techniques such as `nextElementSibling` etc

The buttons all register a single eventlistener which forks logic based upon a `data-set` attibute.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[type="button"]').forEach(bttn=>bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  
  let img=this.parentNode.querySelector('img');
  let text=this.parentNode.querySelector('textarea');
  
  switch(this.dataset.action){
    case 'upvote':
      img.src='img/orangeupvote.png';
      img.classList.toggle(this.dataset.action)
    break;
    case 'downvote':
      img.src='img/orangedownvote.png';
      img.classList.toggle(this.dataset.action)
    break;
    case 'comment':
      text.focus();
      
      let fd=new FormData();
          fd.set('comment',text.value);
          
      fetch('yourposts.php',{method:'post',body:fd})
          .then(r=>r.text())
          .then(text=>{alert(text)})
    break;
    case 'like':
      this.classList.toggle('liked')
    break;
  }
}));
```

```css
.liked{background:blue;color:white}
textarea:focus{background:pink}
.upvote{outline:2px solid green}
.downvote{outline:2px solid red}
```

```html
<div class="textPost">
  <!--
  <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  ?>
 -->
  <h1>Example data</h1>
  <div class="textpostFormat">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor solit...etc #1</p>
    <img />
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='upvote' value='Upvote' />
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='downvote' value='Downvote' />
    <textarea cols=50 rows=5>This is simply a comment...</textarea>
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='comment' value='Comment' />
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='like' value='Like' />
  </div>

  <div class="textpostFormat">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor solit...etc #2</p>
    <img />
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='upvote' value='Upvote' />
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='downvote' value='Downvote' />
    <textarea cols=50 rows=5>Also a simple comment...</textarea>
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='comment' value='Comment' />
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='like' value='Like' />
  </div>
  
  <div class="textpostFormat">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor solit...etc #3</p>
    <img />
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='upvote' value='Upvote' />
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='downvote' value='Downvote' />
    <textarea cols=50 rows=5>Guess what this is...</textarea>
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='comment' value='Comment' />
    <input type='button' class='usr-interaction' data-action='like' value='Like' />
  </div>





</div>
```

Comment: Hey I didn't really understand your answer. Really, I just wanted you to answer what @Phil meant when he said "you're using the same ID value within a loop (id="textpostFormat"). IDs must be unique in a document."

Comment: What is hard to understand in that statement? Every ID in a document **must** be unique - it **cannot** be repeated. You would be advised to ignore IDs for the purposes of your code and use alternative methods of identifying DOM elements - as I showed here.

Comment: Where did I repeat it? Where do I change it?

Comment: In your `while` loop you have `<div class="textpostFormat" id="textpostFormat">` and judging by the javascript code there are other IDs repeated but you failed to show the actual markup when requested so nobody but you knows what/where thigs are repeated other than the one indicated here

Comment: Ok, you've helped me identify where I need to change. Now, what do I need to change?

Comment: If you do not share your code that has all the images and buttons that use ID attributes how can anybody tell you what you need to change?

Comment: But it's the javascript that isn't working. The markup inside that div does not have an y javascript in it.

Comment: Really? I know that!!! Look - the two things are related. The javascript does not work because your HTML markup is invalid. I'm tired of this - you do not wish to help others that are trying to help you - I have asked that you share the actual code ( preferably the bare bones that show the structure and elements of interest ) yet at every opportunity you have failed to do so.

Comment: Ok, check my edited question. I added the markup for everything inside <div class="textPost">

Comment: There are so, so many elements in there that use ID attributes which means that EVERY single one will be repeated inside that loop

Comment: So what do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Stripping all the hideous inline styles and replacing ID attributes with, in this case, simply data-id attributes to yield some example rendered markup like this below. This is NOT intended to be a final solution for you - you need to understand how you fit your functions within this because quite frankly the code given is chaotic.

within the click handler function if you supply the `event` as an argument to the function you can access `event.target` within the function. That `event.target` points to the element that initiated the click. From that point you can use DOM navigation techniques to find other nodes of interest.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.textpostFormat *[data-id]').forEach(n=>n.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  switch( this.dataset.id ){
    case 'textUpvoteImg':
      changetextUpvote(e);
    break;
    case 'textDownvoteImg':
      changetextDownvote(e)
    break;
    case 'makeComment':
      textCommentClick(e);
    break;
    case 'textLike':
      textLikeClick(e);
    break;
  }
}));



function changetextUpvote(e) {
    alert(e.target)
}

function changetextDownvote(e) {
  alert(e.target)
}

function textLikeClick(e) {
  alert(e.target)
}

function textCommentClick(e) {
  alert(e.target)
}
```

```html
<div class='textpostFormat'>
    <a href='profile.php'><img src='img/pfp.png' alt='pfp' class='textpostPFP'></a>
    <div class='textinfo'><b>FIRSTNAME LASTNAME #1</b></div>
    <img src='img/options.png' class='textpostOptions' />

    <div class='textfeedbackBar'>
        <div class='textratingBar'>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>10</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href='profile.php'><img src='img/pfp.png' alt='commentpfp' class='textcommentPFP' /></a>
    <input type='text' name='textComment' class='textComment' data-id='textComment' placeholder='Write a comment' />

    <p>PARAGRAPH - BODY CONTENT #1</p>
    <div class='textPostData'>
        <h4 data-id='textDataLikes'>0 Likes</h4>
        <h4 data-id='textDataComments'>0 Comments</h4>
        <h4 data-id='textDataReactions'>0 Reactions</h4>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 class='textLike' data-id='textLike'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Like</h2>
        <h2 class='makeComment' data-id='makeComment'><i class='fa fa-comment' style='margin-top: 2px;'></i> Comment</h2>
        <h2 class='textReact' data-id='textReact'><i class='fa fa-smile' style='margin-top: 2px;'></i> React</h2>
        <h2 class='textShare' data-id='textShare'><i class='fa fa-share' style='margin-top: 2px'></i> Share</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class='textupvote' data-id='textUpvoteImg' src='img/upvote.png' alt='upvote' />
        <img class='textdownvote' data-id='textDownvoteImg' src='img/downvote.png' alt='downvote' />
    </div>
</div>


<div class='textpostFormat'>
    <a href='profile.php'><img src='img/pfp.png' alt='pfp' class='textpostPFP'></a>
    <div class='textinfo'><b>FIRSTNAME LASTNAME #2</b></div>
    <img src='img/options.png' class='textpostOptions' />

    <div class='textfeedbackBar'>
        <div class='textratingBar'>
            <div>1</div>
            <div>2</div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
            <div>7</div>
            <div>8</div>
            <div>9</div>
            <div>10</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a href='profile.php'><img src='img/pfp.png' alt='commentpfp' class='textcommentPFP' /></a>
    <input type='text' name='textComment' class='textComment' data-id='textComment' placeholder='Write a comment' />

    <p>PARAGRAPH - BODY CONTENT #2</p>
    <div class='textPostData'>
        <h4 data-id='textDataLikes'>0 Likes</h4>
        <h4 data-id='textDataComments'>0 Comments</h4>
        <h4 data-id='textDataReactions'>0 Reactions</h4>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2 class='textLike' data-id='textLike'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> Like</h2>
        <h2 class='makeComment' data-id='makeComment'><i class='fa fa-comment' style='margin-top: 2px;'></i> Comment</h2>
        <h2 class='textReact' data-id='textReact'><i class='fa fa-smile' style='margin-top: 2px;'></i> React</h2>
        <h2 class='textShare' data-id='textShare'><i class='fa fa-share' style='margin-top: 2px'></i> Share</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class='textupvote' data-id='textUpvoteImg' src='img/upvote.png' alt='upvote' />
        <img class='textdownvote' data-id='textDownvoteImg' src='img/downvote.png' alt='downvote' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could we maybe get on a google meet to resolve this? That would be easier for both you and me.